# Connecting Android app to MS SQL database

Tags: java, android, sql-server, database

Can I connect ms sql database to my Android app?

I have a website which uses a database and I want my app to use the same database.
My app is written in eclipse Java.

So how can I do it? Is there some code I can use to do it? Is there a tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try MSSQL-PHP. And call the php scripts from Android.
I had used MySQL with PHP and had found [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) very helpful.

Comment: The download code button there doesn't work :(

Comment: Oops...yes, it doesn't seem to be working. Well, but you would have got some idea from the article and if you plan to do mssql-php way, you could google some other tutorials/code based on this. :)

Comment: All you have to do is use the appropriate driver, i'd recommend using JTDS http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/1.2.5/ , and version 1.2.5 seems to have worked well with android.Detailed instruction on how to use with eclipse can be found http://blog.althafkbacker.com/2013/10/android-and-microsoft-sql-ms-sql-server.html  A working code is available in https://github.com/alkber/AndroidByExample/tree/master/AndroidMSSQL2008